# Dynamically defining instance method within an instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-defined-functions

I have a several classes, each of which define various statistics.

```
class MonthlyStat
  attr_accessor :cost, :size_in_meters
end

class DailyStat
  attr_accessor :cost, :weight
end
```

I want to create a decorator/presenter for a collection of these objects, that lets me easily access aggregate information about each collection, for example:

```
class YearDecorator
  attr_accessor :objs
  def self.[]= *objs
    new objs
  end
  def initialize objs
    self.objs = objs
    define_helpers
  end

  def define_helpers
    if o=objs.first # assume all objects are the same
      o.instance_methods.each do |method_name|
        # sums :cost, :size_in_meters, :weight etc
        define_method "yearly_#{method_name}_sum" do
          objs.inject(0){|o,sum| sum += o.send(method_name)}
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

YearDecorator[mstat1, mstat2].yearly_cost_sum
```

Unfortunately define method isn't available from within an instance method.

Replacing this with:

```
class << self
  define_method "yearly_#{method_name}_sum" do
    objs.inject(0){|o,sum| sum += o.send(method_name)}
  end
end
```

...also fails because the variables method_name and objs which are defined in the instance are no longer available.  Is there an idomatic was to accomplish this in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDITED: I get what you're trying to do now.)

Well, I tried the same approaches that you probably did, but ended up having to use `eval`

```
class Foo
  METHOD_NAMES = [:foo]

  def def_foo
    METHOD_NAMES.each { |method_name|
      eval <<-EOF
        def self.#{method_name}
          \"#{method_name}\".capitalize
        end
      EOF
    }
  end
end

foo=Foo.new

foo.def_foo
p foo.foo # => "Foo"

f2 = Foo.new
p f2.foo # => "undefined method 'foo'..."
```

I myself will admit it's not the most elegant solution (may not even be the most idiomatic) but I've run into similar situations in the past where the most blunt approach that worked was `eval`.

Comment: See my comment above, think this method runs into the same issue.

Comment: It works for me. `class << self` won't work because it's only available within a class scope, where of course the instance variables aren't available. You can't call `define_method` alone in an instance method as you've discovered. But within an instance method calling `class_eval` places you in class scope but with all other local variables visible. Try it.

Comment: Checkout this gist: https://gist.github.com/justinwiley/6379998 , it might better indicate what i'm talking about.  I want the dynamically created methods to apply to only the instance, not be passed on to future instances.

Comment: Holy frijoles, that's one I never thought of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what you're getting for `o.instance_methods`. This is a class-level method and isn't generally available on instances of objects, which from what I can tell, is what you're dealing with here.

Anyway, you probably are looking for `method_missing`, which will define the method dynamically the first time you call it, and will let you send `:define_method` to the object's class. You don't need to redefine the same instance methods every time you instantiate a new object, so `method_missing` will allow you to alter the class at runtime only if the called method hasn't already been defined.

Since you're expecting the name of a method from your other classes surrounded by some pattern (i.e., `yearly_base_sum` would correspond to a `base` method), I'd recommend writing a method that returns a matching pattern if it finds one. Note: this would NOT involve making a list of methods on the other class - you should still rely on the built-in `NoMethodError` for cases when one of your objects doesn't know how to respond to message you send it. This keeps your API a bit more flexible, and would be useful in cases where your stats classes might also be modified at runtime.

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  method_name = matching_method_name(name)
  if method_name
    self.class.send :define_method, name do |*args|
      objs.inject(0) {|obj, sum| sum + obj.send(method_name)}
    end
    send name, *args, &block
  else
    super(name, *args, &block)
  end
end

def matching_method_name(name)
  # ... this part's up to you
end
```

Comment: The issue with this is I want the methods to only apply to a single instance, whereas the above will create the methods on all future instances, right?  So when i'm passing in several MonthStats, I dynamically create :year_size_sum.  If I then pass in DailyStats (which don't have a size method), the year_size_sum method is still defined, since its defined at the class level.

Comment: No, this `method_missing` is defined on the `YearDecorator` class, and the methods it defines remain there as well. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Ahh got it.  Unfortunately that leads to method pollution in future instances.  I think I'm probably going off the Ruby/Rails trying to do this, way too much pain.

Comment: Fair enough. If you're interested in a somewhat better explanation, [this conference talk by Steven Harms](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1MJh4VhrKM) is a good overview of using `method_missing` in a situation similar to yours.